# Reference Request: Lax Ends

Tags: reference-request, higher-category-theory, ct.category-theory

I've read in a few different places that the standard fact
$\text{Nat}\,(F,G) \cong \int_x \text{Hom}\,(Fx,Gx)$
can be upgraded to
$\textbf{LaxNat}\,(F,G) \cong \oint_x\textbf{Hom}\,(Fx,Gx)$.
where the left hand side is the category of lax natural transformations and modifications, and the right hand side is a lax end.

I am looking for a reference that gives the definition of lax end and proves this equivalence.  I do know of the reference, S. Bozapalides, *Théorie formelle des bicatégories*, but I can't read French and I also can't find a copy.  If someone can link me to the Bozapalides reference would be great.  Or even better would be if there is a reference in English.  Thanks!

Comment: I've added the ct.category-theory tag.

Comment: I guess there's an obvious candidate for what a "lax wedge" $c\Rightarrow F$ should be.  Maybe the rest is straightforward too...

Comment: Yes as long as one sticks to strict 2-categories and strict functors, the details in proving the lax transformation identity are not too terrible using the obvious definition of lax wedge/lax end.  I'll take that as evidence that obvious is right in this case.  Still, a reference would be nice.

Comment: BOZAPALIDES, S., Les fins cartésiennes, C. R. A. S. Paris 281 ( 1975)

and

http://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/106961/ArchMath_013-1977-2_3.pdf

Comment: Bozapalides 'Some remarks on lax-presheafs' https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ijm/1256047482

Answer (score 2):

[This page](http://ehres.pagesperso-orange.fr/Cahiers/EsquissesM.htm) says that you may be able to get a copy by emailing Andrée Ehresmann.

I don't know the exact answer to your question, but if you can't find a reference then it may be worth recalling that:

- For Cat-valued F and G, $\mathrm{Nat}(F,G) \simeq \{F,G\}$, the limit of G weighted by F,
- ends are $\hom$-weighted limits, and
- there are lax morphism classifiers for 2-functors, meaning that $\mathrm{Lax}(F,G) \simeq \mathrm{Nat}(QF,G)$ for another 2-functor $QF$.

So if you define the lax end $\oint_x T(x,x)$ to be the representative of $\mathrm{Lax}(\hom_K, L(1,T))$, then you get $\oint_x [F x, G x] \simeq \mathrm{Lax}(\hom_K, [F-, G-])$, which is not quite what you want, but it's close.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, Finn.  I'm still holding out hope for a reference in English, but all of the above is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

A reference is Section 7.1 of [Fosco Loregian's very nice book on coends](https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.02503), which treats co/lax co/ends. In particular, see Example 7.1.9 for a proof of the formula
$$\mathrm{Nat}_\mathrm{lax}(F,G)=\int_{A\in\mathcal{C}}\mkern-2.05em\square\mkern+1.0em\mathsf{Hom}_{\mathcal{D}}(F(A),G(A)).$$
Another reference for bicategorical coends is Chapter 2 of Alexander Corner's thesis ([PDF](http://etheses.whiterose.ac.uk/16767/1/Alexander_Corner_PhD_Thesis.pdf)) or its arXived version, [arXiv:1709.01332 [math.CT]](https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.01332v1).

Comment: P.S. Bozapalides's PhD thesis is available on Libgen.